# What word should be used to describe a FREE TRIP?

Tags: word-request

Does 'FREE TRIP' make you think a trip that you don't have to pay or an unscheduled trip wherever and whenever you want to go?

Is there a more exact expression that describe a FREE TRIP without the meaning of non-pay trip?

Comment: An airline in the U.S. used this tagline in its advertising: _You are now free to move about the country_ (which is a play on words with the announcement made by pilots when they turn off the Fasten Seat Belts sign on an aircraft: "You are now free to move about the cabin"). It's not a standard idiom in English, but it comes close to conveying the sentiment you're asking about. The slogan would probably be recognized by a lot of folks in the U.S., but they would associate it more with that particular airline than with _freedom to travel_.

Comment: So you're asking for a word or phrase that means "an unscheduled trip wherever and whenever you want to go"?

Comment: Yes, but 'Free' has many interpretations that will make others misunderstand...

Comment: Scam! seriously

Answer (score 4):

For a single word, consider the term  *[discretionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discretionary)* (“Available at one's discretion; able to be used as one chooses; left to or regulated by one's own discretion or judgment”).  One can say  “This is a discretionary trip” or  “The trip is entirely discretionary” or “Take the trip at your own discretion”.

Note that *[discretion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discretion#Noun)* has a well-known sense of “being discreet or circumspect” besides its  well-known sense of  “The freedom to make one's own judgements”, so although it's an entirely proper answer to the question, it will confuse some people if you use it.  For that reason, and because it is so easy to briefly and clearly state the intent, I'd just say something like “Take the trip when you like, where you like” or perhaps “The trip is discretionary: take it when you like, where you like”.

Comment: Actually, that's quite a good word. If, for example, I were to offer you a "discretionary cruise" on behalf of Cunard Lines, it would mean that you could take any of their available cruises whenever you wanted. Of course, you would probably have to pay a great deal of money for it!  Another example might be a "fully-refundable" plane ticket.  This ticket (generally quite expensive) will allow you to reschedule your flight whenever you want to, or cancel it altogether with a full refund.  However, it would not allow you to change the destinations.

Answer (score -1):

When I hear this word I will think it is a trip that you have an schedule for your trip. You can not define it word by word.

Answer (score -1):

In the US we have a phrase *a free ride*, as in

> "Were you expecting a free ride?"

It refers to getting something for nothing, and can also be said to someone that tends to be a freeloader (someone who latches onto others to take advantage of them).

At least it is informal language, possibly rude depending on the context.